# FileBrowser is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, file-browser

I was tasked with upgrading a Django 1.3 application up to 1.8. I changed out the applications Filebrowser with a newer version from a Django 1.7 app we also have. Everything is working great, except in the admin, when I try to upload an image with Filebrowser I get the error `ReferenceError: FileBrowser is not defined.` It is being called in this Filebrowser template

filebrowser/templates/filebrowser/custom_field.html

```
/* Part that throws the error -> */ FileBrowser.show('id_image', '/admin/filebrowser/browse/?pop=1&dir=/customer_media');

{% load fb_versions %}
<input id="{{ final_attrs.id }}" type="text" class="vFileBrowseField" name="{{ final_attrs.name }}" value="{{ value }}" /><a href="javascript:FileBrowser.show('{{ final_attrs.id }}', '{% url "fb_browse" %}?pop=1{% if final_attrs.directory %}&amp;dir={{ final_attrs.directory }}{% endif %}{% if final_attrs.format %}&amp;type={{ final_attrs.format }}{% endif %}');" class="fb_show">
    <img src="{{ final_attrs.search_icon }}" alt="" />
</a>
{% ifequal value.filetype "Image" %}
<p class="help" id="help_{{ final_attrs.id }}">
    <a href="{{ value.url_full }}" target="_blank" id="link_{{ final_attrs.id }}">
        <img id="image_{{ final_attrs.id }}" src="{% version value.path final_attrs.ADMIN_THUMBNAIL %}" class="preview" />
    </a>
</p>
{% else %}
<p class="help" id="help_{{ final_attrs.id }}" style="display: none;">
    <a href="javascript://" target="_self" id="link_{{ final_attrs.id }}">
        <img id="image_{{ final_attrs.id }}" class="preview" src="" />
    </a>
</p>
{% endifequal %}
{% if final_attrs.DEBUG %}
<p>
    <strong>Path</strong> {{ value.path }}<br />
    <strong>FileType</strong> {{ value.filetype }}<br /><br />
    <strong>Directory</strong> {{ final_attrs.directory }}<br />
    <strong>Extensions</strong> {{ final_attrs.extensions }}<br />
    <strong>Format</strong> {{ final_attrs.format }}
</p>
{% endif %}
```

I am also getting this error, even though I can see that jquery is being loaded in the network tab of my chrome debugger.

```
TypeError: $ is not a function

├── admin_media
│   └── js
├── customer_media
│   └── js
├── site_media
│   ├── js
├── sqlite
│   └── endeavor.db
├── templates
│   ├── admin
│   │   └── base_site.html
│   ├── base.html
│   ├── detail
│   │   ├── detail_base.html
│   │   └── detail_page.html
│   ├── donation.html
│   ├── faqs.html
│   ├── fund_list.html
│   ├── home.html
│   ├── news
│   │   ├── news_article.html
│   │   ├── news_articles.html
│   │   └── news_list.html
│   ├── staff.html
│   └── thank_you.html
├── webapp
│   ├── DoImport.py
│   ├── FundsList.csv
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── filebrowser
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── __init__.pyc
│   │   ├── base.py
│   │   ├── base.pyc
│   │   ├── conf.py
│   │   ├── conf.pyc
│   │   ├── decorators.py
│   │   ├── fields.py
│   │   ├── fields.pyc
│   │   ├── forms.py
│   │   ├── functions.py
│   │   ├── management
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   └── commands
│   │   │       ├── __init__.py
│   │   │       └── version_generator.py
│   │   ├── models.py
│   │   ├── settings.py
│   │   ├── static
│   │   │   └── filebrowser
│   │   │       ├── js
│   │   │       │   ├── AddFileBrowser.js
│   │   │       │   ├── FB_CKEditor.js
│   │   │       │   ├── FB_FileBrowseField.js
│   │   │       │   ├── FB_Redactor.js
│   │   │       │   ├── FB_TinyMCE.js
│   │   │       │   └── TinyMCEAdmin.js
│   │   │       └── uploadify
│   │   │           ├── Instructions.txt
│   │   │           ├── Sample
│   │   │           │   ├── check-exists.php
│   │   │           │   ├── index.php
│   │   │           │   ├── jquery.min.js
│   │   │           │   ├── jquery.uploadifive.min.js
│   │   │           │   ├── uploadifive-cancel.png
│   │   │           │   ├── uploadifive-image-only.php
│   │   │           │   ├── uploadifive.css
│   │   │           │   └── uploadifive.php
│   │   │           ├── change-log.txt
│   │   │           ├── check-exists.php
│   │   │           ├── index.php
│   │   │           ├── jquery.min.js
│   │   │           ├── jquery.uploadifive.js
│   │   │           ├── jquery.uploadifive.min.js
│   │   │           ├── license-commercial.txt
│   │   │           ├── uploadifive-cancel.png
│   │   │           ├── uploadifive-image-only.php
│   │   │           ├── uploadifive.css
│   │   │           └── uploadifive.php
│   │   ├── templates
│   │   │   └── filebrowser
│   │   │       ├── append.html
│   │   │       ├── custom_field.html
│   │   │       ├── include
│   │   │       │   ├── _response.html
│   │   │       │   ├── breadcrumbs.html
│   │   │       │   ├── filelisting.html
│   │   │       │   ├── filter.html
│   │   │       │   ├── paginator.html
│   │   │       │   ├── search.html
│   │   │       │   ├── tableheader.html
│   │   │       │   └── toolbar.html
│   │   │       ├── index.html
│   │   │       ├── makedir.html
│   │   │       ├── rename.html
│   │   │       ├── upload.html
│   │   │       └── versions.html
│   │   ├── templatetags
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   ├── fb_csrf.py
│   │   │   ├── fb_pagination.py
│   │   │   ├── fb_tags.py
│   │   │   └── fb_versions.py
│   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   └── views.py
│   ├── fund_list.csv
│   ├── manage.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── sslDecorator.py
│   ├── static
│   │   ├── admin
│   │   │   └── js
│   │   │       ├── LICENSE-JQUERY.txt
│   │   │       ├── SelectBox.js
│   │   │       ├── SelectFilter2.js
│   │   │       ├── actions.js
│   │   │       ├── actions.min.js
│   │   │       ├── admin
│   │   │       │   ├── DateTimeShortcuts.js
│   │   │       │   └── RelatedObjectLookups.js
│   │   │       ├── calendar.js
│   │   │       ├── collapse.js
│   │   │       ├── collapse.min.js
│   │   │       ├── core.js
│   │   │       ├── inlines.js
│   │   │       ├── inlines.min.js
│   │   │       ├── jquery.init.js
│   │   │       ├── jquery.js
│   │   │       ├── jquery.min.js
│   │   │       ├── prepopulate.js
│   │   │       ├── prepopulate.min.js
│   │   │       ├── related-widget-wrapper.js
│   │   │       ├── timeparse.js
│   │   │       └── urlify.js
│   │   └── filebrowser
│   │       ├── css
│   │       │   ├── filebrowser.css
│   │       │   └── suit-filebrowser.css
│   │       ├── img
│   │       │   ├── explorer.png
│   │       │   ├── filebrowser_icon_delete.gif
│   │       │   ├── filebrowser_icon_delete_hover.gif
│   │       │   ├── filebrowser_icon_rename.gif
│   │       │   ├── filebrowser_icon_rename_hover.gif
│   │       │   ├── filebrowser_icon_select.gif
│   │       │   ├── filebrowser_icon_select_disabled.gif
│   │       │   ├── filebrowser_icon_select_hover.gif
│   │       │   ├── filebrowser_icon_show.gif
│   │       │   ├── filebrowser_icon_show_hover.gif
│   │       │   ├── filebrowser_icon_showversions.gif
│   │       │   ├── filebrowser_icon_showversions_hover.gif
│   │       │   ├── filebrowser_type_.gif
│   │       │   ├── filebrowser_type_audio.gif
│   │       │   ├── filebrowser_type_code.gif
│   │       │   ├── filebrowser_type_document.gif
│   │       │   ├── filebrowser_type_folder.gif
│   │       │   ├── filebrowser_type_image.gif
│   │       │   ├── filebrowser_type_video.gif
│   │       │   ├── icon-fb-preview-hover.png
│   │       │   ├── icon-fb-preview.png
│   │       │   ├── icon-fb-view-image-hover.png
│   │       │   ├── icon-pulldown-actions-active.png
│   │       │   ├── icon-pulldown-actions-hover.png
│   │       │   ├── icon-pulldown-actions.png
│   │       │   ├── icon-searchbox.png
│   │       │   └── icon-showversions.png
│   │       ├── js
│   │       │   ├── AddFileBrowser.js
│   │       │   ├── FB_CKEditor.js
│   │       │   ├── FB_FileBrowseField.js
│   │       │   ├── FB_Redactor.js
│   │       │   ├── FB_TinyMCE.js
│   │       │   └── TinyMCEAdmin.js
│   │       └── uploadify
│   │           ├── Instructions.txt
│   │           ├── Sample
│   │           │   ├── check-exists.php
│   │           │   ├── index.php
│   │           │   ├── jquery.min.js
│   │           │   ├── jquery.uploadifive.min.js
│   │           │   ├── uploadifive-cancel.png
│   │           │   ├── uploadifive-image-only.php
│   │           │   ├── uploadifive.css
│   │           │   └── uploadifive.php
│   │           ├── change-log.txt
│   │           ├── check-exists.php
│   │           ├── index.php
│   │           ├── jquery.min.js
│   │           ├── jquery.uploadifive.js
│   │           ├── jquery.uploadifive.min.js
│   │           ├── license-commercial.txt
│   │           ├── uploadifive-cancel.png
│   │           ├── uploadifive-image-only.php
│   │           ├── uploadifive.css
│   │           └── uploadifive.php
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── utility.py
│   ├── views.py
│   └── wsgi.py
└── webapp_admin
```

Settings

```
import logging
import os

import sys
from posixpathhelp import parentpath

PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
PROJECT_PARENT = parentpath(PROJECT_ROOT)

sys.path.insert(0, PROJECT_ROOT)

DEVELOPMENT = False

# Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
SECRET_KEY = ''

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*', ]

SITE_ID = 1

# EMAIL SETTINGS
EMAILTO = 'xxxxx@xxxxx.com'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = xxx
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'xxxxx@xxxx.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'xxxxxxx'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True

# Application definition
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'filebrowser',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sitemaps',
    'tinymce',
    'content',
    'page_content',
    'staff',
    'news',
    'donation',
    'paypal.standard',
    'paypal.pro',
    'paypal.standard.ipn',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    # 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
)

from django.conf.global_settings import TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS as TCP

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = TCP + (
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    'common_context_processors.common_context',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'webapp.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'webapp.wsgi.application'

TIME_ZONE = 'America/New_York'

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_PARENT, "site_media/")
CUSTOMER_MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_PARENT, "customer_media/")

MEDIA_URL = '/site_media/'
CUSTOMER_MEDIA_URL = '/customer_media/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS = 0644

SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 3600
SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True
SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST = True

LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': True,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(filename)s %(funcName)s %(lineno)d %(message)s'
        },
        'normal': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(funcName)s %(message)s'
        },
        'simple': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'verbose'
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'webapp': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
        '': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
        },
    }
}

DJANGO_FRONT_ALLOWED_EDITORS = ['tinymce', ]
DJANGO_FRONT_EDIT_MODE = 'inline'
DJANGO_FRONT_EDITOR_OPTIONS = {
    'filebrowserBrowseUrl': '/admin/filebrowser/browse/?pop=3',
    'contentsCss': '/static/css/contents.css'
}

DJANGO_FRONT_KEY = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'  # MAKE THIS UNIQUE PER SETTINGS FILE

TRACKING_RESULTS_PER_PAGE = 50

ADMINS = (
    ('XXXX XXXXXXXX', 'xxxxxx@xxxxxx'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': os.path.join(PROJECT_PARENT, "sqlite/endeavor.db"),  # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': '',  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': '',  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '',  # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '',  # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}

if DEVELOPMENT:
    ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/admin_media/'
else:
    ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/admin_media/'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            # insert your TEMPLATE_DIRS here
            os.path.join(PROJECT_PARENT, "templates"),
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                # Insert your TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS here or use this
                # list if you haven't customized them:
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
                'django.template.context_processors.media',
                'django.template.context_processors.static',
                'django.template.context_processors.tz',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

PAYPAL_TEST = False  # Testing mode on
PAYPAL_WPP_USER = "xxxxxxxxx"  # Get from PayPal
PAYPAL_WPP_PASSWORD = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
PAYPAL_WPP_SIGNATURE = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
PAYPAL_RECEIVER_EMAIL = "xxx@xxxx.com"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your error message:

```
TypeError: $ is not a function
```

It looks like the jQuery global variable `$` isn't getting loaded.

Are you sure your jQuery static file `jquery.min.js` is getting loaded correctly?

Comment: Thats what it was. It turns out there was just a lot of javascript files that hadn't been pushed up for some reason. I understood why filebrowser wasn't working than, but it was odd that jquery still wasn't being loaded because I had a CDN for it in my base template. Either way, thanks Nathan !